# Events on browser put asleep or closed in IdentityModel.OidcClient

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, identityserver4

I manage to add hybrid authentication using IdentityServer at backend and Xamarin.Forms Asnroid app as client using [IdentityModel.OidcClient](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient). All works well with the browser open and can login without any issues.

Now, I have a scenario where the user goes to the opening page and clicked login, and the browser opens with login page shown, then they decided to just **close/kill the browser or put asleep in Android**. Surely it will return to the opening page. But I wanted to capture this event at the opening page as well. as this code below does not return anything yet if not Logged in first.

```
_result = await _client.LoginAsync(new LoginRequest());
```

I also use the `ChromeCustomTabsBrowser.cs` following the sample.

```
public class ChromeCustomTabsBrowser : IBrowser
{
    private readonly Activity _context;
    private readonly CustomTabsActivityManager _manager;

    public ChromeCustomTabsBrowser() :
        this CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity) { }


    public ChromeCustomTabsBrowser(Activity context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _manager = new CustomTabsActivityManager(_context);
    }

    public Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options)
    {
        var task = new TaskCompletionSource<BrowserResult>();

        var builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder(_manager.Session)
           .SetToolbarColor(Color.Argb(255, 52, 152, 219))
           .SetShowTitle(true)
           .EnableUrlBarHiding();

        var customTabsIntent = builder.Build();

        // ensures the intent is not kept in the history stack, which makes
        // sure navigating away from it will close it
        customTabsIntent.Intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);

        Action<string> callback = null;
        callback = url =>
        {
            OidcCallbackActivity.Callbacks -= callback;

            task.SetResult(new BrowserResult()
            {
                Response = url
            });
        };

        OidcCallbackActivity.Callbacks += callback;

        customTabsIntent.LaunchUrl(_context,
            Android.Net.Uri.Parse(options.StartUrl));

        return task.Task;
    }

}
```

Is there away to capture this event? I was hoping there is an event that we can tapped while doing hybrid authentication, something like e.g.:

`_client.OnBrowserClosed += ...`

or,

`_client.OnBrowserTabClosed += ...`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I did not add

```
LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask
```

on Android MainActivity.

Comment: When setting LaunchMode to SingleTask did the _client.LoginAsync returned a result when closing or did you grab that event on OnResume? iOS correctly returns error with "UserCancel" message, but Android does not returns anything even on SingleTask. Thanks!